# Script to copy a changing range to cell B2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script to copy a range of cells to cell B2. The range to copy from changes each time so want to highlight the top left cell and then the script takes it from there. What I have so far is:

```
function CopyToB2() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
var selectedColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
var selectedRow = cellRange.getRow();
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(selectedColumn,selectedRow,2,43);
range.setValues(range);
spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

but get the error

> Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Range) don't match the
> method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Comment: You want to get a range o values and paste it in a single cell B2? Can you provide a screenshot of the input and the desired output? or even a spreadsheet ? Also the error you are getting is clear. You are using `setValues` but instead of passing values you are passing a range object.

Comment: soMarios So it will always be 5 cols wide by 42 rows down, may start at G2 another time at AA2 or any number of areas. I need to click on the top left cell in the range required and then the script should copy the range to B2 (and always to B2)

Comment: but when you say B2 you mean starting from B2 until wherever the range stops.

Comment: soMarios Yes, the range will always be the same size and always copied to B2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

- The main issue with your code is that you pass a `range` object in the `setValues` function and therefore you are getting this error.
- A second issue is that you passed the parameters of the [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) function in the wrong order. It should be:

  ```
  getRange(selectedRow,selectedColumn,43,2)
  ```

instead of `getRange(selectedColumn,selectedRow,2,43)`

- A third issue is that you need to define the range that the data will be pasted to and that can't be just a single cell `B2` in this case. What you need to do is to define `B2` as the **start** of your pasting range and then set the values of your active range.

**Solution:**

```
function CopyToB2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var selectedColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
  var selectedRow = cellRange.getRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,selectedColumn,43,2).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(2,2,dataRange.length,dataRange[0].length).setValues(dataRange);
};
```

Comment: Many Thanks soMarios That works a treat. Thank you also for the explanation, very good of you. Regards Ben